# Hollywood movie where a person takes different roles but escapes most of time

Tags: identify-this-movie

I read about a **hollywood** movie where the plot goes on similar to this.

A person takes different roles (pilot, banker, etc., ) and cheats continuously but escapes most of the time. He starts cheating at a very early stage. Disguises most of the times in many different roles yet no one to identify him.

blah blah blah
(A women comes in his life.)
blah blah blah

Finally he gets caught and ends up in a prison. The inspector (who was following him and who caught him) finally helps him release....

Also remember that the lead role has a sister.

Definitely a **hollywood** film *but having a doubt if the lead role was played by **Tom Cruise***

I also remember this movie in  Imdb has a good rating too but I am not getting the movie name.

Comment: Sounds like [catch me if you can](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264464/)

Comment: Note that the movie is based on a true story; I'm not sure what details in the movie itself are true, but the main character is a real person, who really did impersonate many different professions including pilot (and really did steal millions of dollars), really did get caught and go to prison, and now really does work for the FBI. He wrote a fascinating editorial about identity theft in the mid-2000s, which included a claim similar to "if I did it today, I'd steal thirty times as much money, in a third of the time, and I would *never* get caught."

Comment: "I concur" (that it's catch me if you can)

Comment: @KRyan: Interesting. any links further reading ?

Comment: I can't find the exact article I mention, but a search for "Frank Abagnale identity theft" turns up several others, as well as places you can buy his book.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[Catch Me If You Can(2002)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264464/)

> A true story about Frank Abagnale Jr., who, before his 19th birthday, successfully conned millions of dollars' worth of checks as a Pan Am pilot, doctor, and legal prosecutor.

Comment: The only thing that makes me question this is the sister. I don't think Frank Abagnale Jr had a sister in the movie (except maybe a half sister when he discovers his mother's new family at the end)?

Comment: @Rikki: Ha yes! I meant the half sister ;)

Answer (score 3):

Another, somewhat similar, older movie is [The Great Impostor (1961)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053879/) starring Tony Curtis.

> Based on a true story, a bright young man who hasn't the patience for the normal way of advancement finds that people rarely question you if your papers are in order. He becomes a marine, a monk, a surgeon onboard a Canadian Warship, and a prison warden.

Note that Frank Demara (whose life the story is based on) was not a fraudster in the same way that Frank Abagnale Jr. was. Demara pretended to credentials he didn't have, but monetary gain was not his goal (or his destiny).

Answer (score 1):

The first movie that came to mind in answer to your question is [The Saint](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120053/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl).

One of the main characters in the movie disguises himself as various Catholic saints and successfully steals high profile items & avoids the law. It's a fun show and I recommend it, though after re-reading your question I suspect you are looking for Catch Me If You Can like New-To-IT suggested.